# Float left brakes if one elment has more height

Tags: html, css, css-float

The desired output is:

[image]

But I can NOT set height to the elements cause some have more and other have less content.

This is what I get:

[image]

**Snippet**

```css
.wrap {
  width: 400px;
}

.inner {
  width: 80px;
  border:solid 2px lime;
  margin: 5px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inner"><h1>1</h1>blubby blubby bluuu</div>
  <div class="inner"><h1>2</h1>blubby blubby bluuu</div>
  <div class="inner"><h1>3</h1>blubby blubby bluuu</div>
  <div class="inner"><h1>4</h1>blubby blubby bluuublubby blubby bluuu</div>
  <div class="inner"><h1>5</h1>blubby blubby bluuu</div>
  <div class="inner"><h1>6</h1>blubby blubby bluuublubby blubby bluuu</div>
  <div class="inner"><h1>7</h1>blubby blubby bluuu</div>
  <div class="inner"><h1>8</h1>blubby blubby bluuu</div>
  <div class="inner"><h1>9</h1>blubby blubby bluuu</div>
  <div class="inner"><h1>10</h1>blubby blubby bluuu</div>
  <div class="inner"><h1>11</h1>blubby blubby bluuu</div>
  <div class="inner"><h1>12</h1>blubby blubby bluuu</div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hhmqo4ap/)**

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `display:inline-block` instead

```css
.wrap {
  width: 400px;
}

.inner {
  width: 80px;
  border:solid 2px lime;
  margin: 5px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top
    
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inner"><h1>1</h1>blubby blubby bluuu</div>
  <div class="inner"><h1>2</h1>blubby blubby bluuu</div>
  <div class="inner"><h1>3</h1>blubby blubby bluuu</div>
  <div class="inner"><h1>4</h1>blubby blubby bluuublubby blubby bluuu</div>
  <div class="inner"><h1>5</h1>blubby blubby bluuu</div>
  <div class="inner"><h1>6</h1>blubby blubby bluuublubby blubby bluuu</div>
  <div class="inner"><h1>7</h1>blubby blubby bluuu</div>
  <div class="inner"><h1>8</h1>blubby blubby bluuu</div>
  <div class="inner"><h1>9</h1>blubby blubby bluuu</div>
  <div class="inner"><h1>10</h1>blubby blubby bluuu</div>
  <div class="inner"><h1>11</h1>blubby blubby bluuu</div>
  <div class="inner"><h1>12</h1>blubby blubby bluuu</div>
</div>
```